# Explanation for Planck 2018 temperature fluctuations strongest peaks

Tags: astrophysics, temperature, formation, cosmic-microwave-background

As it can be seen from Plank 2018 Cosmic Microwave Background [temperature fluctuations](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2020/09/aa33910-18/F1.html) data-

[image]

There are 3 sharp peaks at multipole expansions $\ell \approx 250, 550, 800 $. Also as multipole expansion goes on and adds more details to angular sensitivity of temperature fluctuations,- these fluctuations are damped-down almost exponentially. First question would be,- Why there are exactly 3 sharp peaks of CMB temperature fluctuations and what they are mapped to with respect to universe evolution timeline / structures/matter formation ? Are these peaks somehow related to the fact that universe is composed of ordinary matter, dark matter and dark energy, or this is irrelevant information ? And second question would be Why temperature fluctuations are decreased almost exponentially as multipole expansion goes on ? Thanks.

Comment: I’m no cosmologist and my understanding is limited, but here’s what I remember from my undergraduate cosmology class: first peak location on x axis is related to curvature of the universe, location of first peak on y axis is related to total mass density ($\Omega_M$), second peak y axis location related to baryonic matter (higher y value means less baryonic matter) and third peak y axis is related to dark matter amount. I have some very nice graphs illustrating this from my notes, but I have no idea what the source material is for it, that said I can share if you’re interested.

Comment: I would also add that I remember distinctly my professor saying this structure is some of the most compelling evidence we have for dark energy/ matter

Comment: Thanks, Can you expand on this in a bit more detailed version posting it in your answer ?